# Create rainbow histogram with bin labels ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram with a rainbow color scale but I also want to have the bin labels. I have been able to create a histogram with labeled bins and I have read a couple of posts talking about how to make a rainbow histogram which I have been able to recreate ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795211/coloring-a-geom-histogram-by-gradient/43795338#43795338) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284227/how-to-fill-histogram-with-color-gradient)). However, I have not been able to create a rainbow histogram with the correct bin labels. I will attach an example data set and some sample code that I have tried. Ideally, I would also like to remove any bin labels that have zero as a value but I don't want to be too greedy here.

```
ggplot(final_df,aes(x=V1, fill = cut(V1, 25)))+ geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.., label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5)
```

[image: Example1]

As you can see, it creates the rainbow histogram but the bin labels are all messed up.

```
structure(list(V1 = c(18, 0, 20, 21, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 16, 
0, 0, 20, 20, 2, 0, 19, 22, 0, 0, 19, 0, 22, 22, 19, 2, 0, 0, 
1, 18, 23, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 21, 21, 0, 0, 15, 24, 0, 20, 19, 
0, 1, 20, 21, 0, 0, 20, 22, 20, 0, 21, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 23, 
2, 1, 1, 21, 0, 2, 3, 23, 23, 1, 22, 0, 19, 23, 1, 2, 23, 1, 
0, 0, 20, 1, 0, 0, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 23, 
1, 0, 23, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 18, 16, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 22, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0, 1, 18, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 20, 2, 
0, 1, 22, 0, 1, 23, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 10, 1, 17, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 23, 2, 19, 2, 1, 21, 3, 
0, 0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 24, 2, 1, 1, 23, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
22, 23, 0, 23, 0, 22, 2, 19, 0, 20, 22, 0, 23, 0, 21, 0, 0, 23, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 22, 1, 0, 1, 22, 22, 20, 0, 1, 2, 22, 2, 23, 0, 
18, 1, 23, 0, 2, 0, 1, 22, 0, 21, 0, 2, 20, 0, 0, 23, 0, 1, 18, 
0, 18, 20, 1, 0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 0, 17, 20, 0, 0, 1, 22, 20, 22, 
2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 2, 22, 20, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 21, 21, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 24, 0, 0, 22, 17, 0, 1, 20, 1, 1, 21, 1, 21, 21, 0, 
21, 0, 1, 23, 0, 0, 23, 21, 0, 0, 24, 0, 6, 17, 0, 21, 0, 23, 
0, 0, 22, 1, 1, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 19, 0, 21, 21, 2, 1, 18, 1, 
21, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 23, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
25, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0, 21, 19, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 22, 22, 0, 19, 0, 3, 0, 21, 0, 1, 20, 1, 1, 1, 22, 1, 
22, 1, 22, 1, 0, 2, 0, 25, 23, 0, 20, 0, 2, 22, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
23, 22, 0, 1, 19, 23, 1, 0, 2, 0, 18, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 21, 0, 21, 20, 0, 1, 19, 23, 0, 1, 23, 0, 
1, 22, 21, 3, 0, 22, 2, 0, 1, 23, 2, 0, 24, 23, 21, 23, 20, 0, 
0, 0, 20, 22, 0, 2, 0, 17, 0, 0, 1, 22, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 
5, 21, 21, 1, 19, 18, 0, 24, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 23, 1, 20, 0, 0, 1, 19, 22, 21, 24, 3, 1, 2, 24, 0, 0, 23, 
17, 22, 0, 24, 23, 16, 1, 0, 2, 20, 0, 19, 0, 2, 1, 22, 20, 0, 
20, 0, 1, 22, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 25, 24, 2, 20, 3, 0, 
0, 23, 0, 4, 0, 19, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 19, 22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
23, 20, 20, 23, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 21, 20, 23, 0, 1, 1, 0, 19, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 22, 0, 22, 0, 1, 18, 0, 20, 1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 23, 19, 21, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
23, 21, 21, 4, 20, 24, 0, 3, 0, 20, 23, 1, 23, 21, 20, 18, 0, 
21, 2, 1, 21, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -713L
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you manually bin your `V1` variable using `cut(V1, 25`. Thereby you get 25 groups which (while most of the time having a zero count) get stacked on top of each other. Hence, you end up with 25 stacked (and overlapping) labels per bin. Instead make use of the bins computed by `stat_bin` by mapping `factor(..x..)` on `fill`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(final_df, aes(x = V1, fill = factor(..x..))) +
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE) 

p +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..), geom = "text", vjust = -.5)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

To get rid of the zero entries you could make use of an `ifelse`:

```r
p +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., label = ifelse(..count.. > 0, ..count.., "")), geom = "text", vjust = -.5)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]